# Flash Gordon comic where they treat Ming for common cold?

Tags: story-identification, comics, flash-gordon

I am trying to find a *Flash Gordon* comic in which the protagonists are forcibly brought somewhere (Mongo?) and have to treat the antagonist (possibly Emperor Ming) for a dreadful illness, which turns out to be a bad case of the cold/flu in the end.

I might have read this as a print comic book in the mid '90s, and even then it was part of an old collection.

Which issue am I remembering?

Comment: I don't have the actual comic but there are references online to a July 1960 Flash Gordon strip regarding a virus on a space station..

http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/cole_09_14/

Answer (score 2):

It is in a comic "The Queen of Darkness".

@Alith: Curiously enough, interferon is Dr. Zarkov's preferred treatment here as well.

[image]
[image]